# convert .docx to .txt in command line for batch file

Tags: ms-word, converters

missing link ~ I have a working batch file that takes .txt input.  The data is in MS WORD and we have to manually 'save as .txt' each of hundreds of files before running the batch file.  Commercial converters run from $50 to $500 . . . ANY help appreciated!

Comment: btw ~ there are many online free converters, but they are not time/effort savers over what we're doing now. 
BUT could these solutions be packaged for .bat file use ??

Comment: CLOSE ISSUE ~ R E S O L V E D
not easy, but found a way to use Pandoc!